# Regex: Keep unkknown substring

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio, notepad++

I try to modify a set of strings. I need to replace some unknown parts but also keep the unkknown middle part. In notepad++ I used this

as regex-input: `.*(ThemeResource .*?Brush).*`

and regex-output: `/1`

with this result:

Input:

```
"<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />"
"<Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltMediumLowBrush}" />"
"<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />"
"<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundAltMediumBrush}" />"
```

Output:

```
"ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush"
"ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltMediumLowBrush"
"ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumLowBrush"
"ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundAltMediumBrush"
```

but with c#-regex my output is allways: `"/1"`

I guess, there are fundamental differences between c# and notepad++ regex, but do not understand what to change, since my regex-input-selection seems to work as expected.

Edit:

My code:

```
List<string> ls = File.ReadLines(@"c:\cbTemplate.xml").ToList().Select(x=>Regex.Replace(x, ".*{(ThemeResource .*?Brush).*", @"\1"));
```

My notepad++ "Find and Replace":

[image]

Comment: Here's a good [introduction](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex)

Comment: Can you please add your implementation code?

Comment: @ferdy I added my code-string

Comment: { is special character, preceed with \

Comment: @KubaWyrostek it tells me "unknown escape sequence"

Comment: Use $1 instead of \1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the capturing group, use `$1` instead of `/1`:

```
List<string> ls = File.ReadLines(@"c:\cbTemplate.xml").ToList().Select(x=>Regex.Replace(x, ".*{(ThemeResource .*?Brush).*", @"$1"));
```